# ARM Neon VLD1 instruction loading register twice

Tags: xcode, assembly, arm, lldb, neon

The following code loads identical data into D16,D17 as well as D18,D19:

```
vld1.16         {d16, d17, d18, d19}, [R1, :128]!
```

I tried splitting the loads out separately like so

```
vld1.16         d16, [R1, :64]!
```

This also loaded the data twice into d16 and d17.

This is under Xcode 5.1.1, target was an iPad 3 (ARMv7).

Not believing the results in the IDE, I checked the results in lldb, got the same.

Disassembly of the code in lldb shows the expected code.

Comment: Try removing the `,:128` part.

Comment: No good. Tried removing the alignment specifier already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Xcode. The load is actually working properly.

If I dump out the contents using the d registers, I get the duplicate values:

```
(lldb) register read d16 --format int16_t[]
     d16 = {1210 -18 14 -9}
(lldb) register read d17 --format int16_t[]
     d17 = {1210 -18 14 -9}
```

However if I look at that data using the q8 register (which is aliased to d16 and d17) the values look right:

```
(lldb) register read q8 --format int16_t[]
     q8 = {1210 -18 14 -9 23 -9 -14 -18}
```

So looks like a bug with LLDB that needs to be fixed, don't trust what it tells you about the d registers!

Comment: What makes this even more annoying is another bug in the xcode IDE that only allows you to view the Q registers as hex bytes. So the lldb commands are the way to easily interpret the Q register.